# React router. Cannot GET when refreshing a page or write url manually

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-routing

I am trying to build a SPA with react router. When I am navigating with link it works perfect, but with refreshing or writting url it gives me `cannot GET /(any route except main)`. I was trying to add `historyApiFallback : true` option to my webpack dev server configs but it didnt solved it.

I will appreciate  any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented (and now I have written 30 characters): https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/v2.3.0/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory

Comment: Thank you, Ryan!!! I wrote a server using your example, but I faced another problem. I got an `unexpected < token ` error . After I added type=text/jsx to my script tag in index.html, no errors but page just doesnt displaying after refreshing...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is your issue? [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually?rq=1)

It might be helpful if you included the code from your router in the question as well.

Comment: Thank you! yes I saw that question . And I am still trying to implement a server, but it doesnt work properly. Router.run is deprecated... I  thought it might be an easier way to do this without writting a server.

Answer (score -1):

Use HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter

Comment: Why? You can't just post a one liner like that without an explanation.